# How to input a value to textbox in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to input a value from my website to another website loaded in the iframe.
For example, I loaded gmail.com in my iframe and i need to input login credentials from my website.

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('content_frame');
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var elem = document.getElementById('userEmail');
```

while executing the second line, i've got the below error

```
SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that because of [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) .